# Possible to use IE behavior to enable :checked support?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

trying to create custom radio/checkbox style that will work for Wufoo forms. Wufoo forms only allows CSS so no way I can use JS polyfills like Selectivzr.js unfortunately :(

Anyone know of a behavior script (.htc) that provides some CSS 3 selector support in older versions of IE? I've been Googling to now avail... alot of them are for border radius and gradients only

Comment: You can try CSS3 PIE http://css3pie.com ?

Comment: unfortunately thats for decorations only  http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/